# vdo on a ramdisk vs on an ssd

Tags: windows-11, redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-kvm, ramdisk

I have ramdisk created with vdo in redhat like this as a systemd service mounted during bootup in  `/etc/systemd/system/my_lv.service`

```
  vgcreate my_vg /dev/ram0; \
  lvcreate --type vdo -n my_lv -l 17919 -V 700G  --config "allocation/vdo_slab_size_mb=1024" my_vg; \
  mkfs.ext4 -K /dev/my_vg/my_lv; \
  mount /dev/my_vg/my_lv /mnt/ramdisk; \
  lvmdevices -y --deldev /dev/ram0'
```

I find it very useful since i can run multiple operating systems in just **70GB of ramdisk** which would probably occupy more than 200GB of space on an a normal device without vdo.

```
guest os : windows 11 64 bit
host os : redhat 9
ramdisk size : 70 GB ( ramdisk is configured with vdo with the commands shown above)
```

1. How would a 70GB ssd configured with vdo fare against 70GB of ramdisk configured with vdo to store qcow2 images to run qemu-KVM guests.
2. is it possible to enable some kind of direct I/O to improve the performance when ramdisk is used since i read online swaping will reduce the the performance of the ramdisk and it will not be much faster than SSD.

Also, Since there is lot of conflicting information online. please clarify if using ramdisk will improve kvm guest performance and if i can enable direct i/o to improve performance. if so how?